# Why does python selenium send keys not input my keys sometimes?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I'm trying to code an auto gmail maker, and I'm on the part where it is confirming the phone number. When I run this code, I get:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element:
>
> Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":"[id="phoneNumberId"]"},

and it does not enter in the phone number. But when I remove the try except block, it enters in the phone number, which is strange because shouldn't the try execute block not affect the code above? Also, the CSS selector I put definitely exists, I can see it in the html. Any help is appreciated!
Here is the code for this part:

```
phonenum = browser.find_element_by_id("phoneNumberId")
phonenum.send_keys('8888888888')
try:
    ll = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.FliLIb.DL0QTb')))
except:
    print('error')
```

Comment: Removing the try/except can't possibly have any effect on code that comes _before_.

Comment: That message means it's not there so either it's in a iframe or you need to wait for it

Comment: @John Gordon- that’s what I thought too, but when I remove the try except statement the code above works normally, and when I add it back, the send phone number code doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

You should add wait to let the `phonenum` element loaded.
Like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

phonenum = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "phoneNumberId")))
phonenum.send_keys('8888888888')
```

Comment: This question is regarding this `But when I remove the try except block, it enters in the phone number, which is strange because shouldn't the try execute block not affect the code above`

Comment: @cruisepandey maybe. let's see what the TS will replay. So far I see no any reaction from him

Comment: @Prophet ok I’ll try it when I get home tonight and I’ll let you know, thanks

Comment: @Prophet I tried the code but I got this error: TypeError: until() missing 1 required positional argument: 'method', which is strange because the other explicit waits I used worked

Comment: maybe because you didn't instantiate the wait object as respected. I forgot to put that in the code. Sorry. This: `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)` . See if this works now